# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a simple USPS Tracking Bot for Discord.

It works by using the `!usps TRACKING NUMBER` command in Discord

Here is the code:

```
import shippo
import discord
import asyncio
import datetime

token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client = discord.Client()
shippo.config.api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('-------------------------')
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('-------------------------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!help'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Help", description="Use `!uSps TRACKING NUMBER` to get started!", color=0x8B4513)
        embed.set_author(name="USPS Tracking", url="https://www.usps.com/", icon_url="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/usps-png-logo/bridgeport-apartments-usps-png-logo-2.png")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/usps-png-logo/bridgeport-apartments-usps-png-logo-2.png")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

    if message.content.startswith('!'):
        cmd = message.content.split()[0].lower()[1:]
        args = message.content.split()[1:]
        packageTrack = ' '.join(args)
        tracking_number = packageTrack
        carrier_token = 'usps'
        tracking = shippo.Track.get_status(carrier_token, tracking_number)
        d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(tracking['tracking_status']['status_date'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        new_format = "%m-%d-%Y" + " at " + "%H:%M"

        uspsStatus = tracking['tracking_status']['status_details'] + " - " + tracking['tracking_status']['status']
        uspsCity = tracking['tracking_status']['location']['city']
        uspsState = tracking['tracking_status']['location']['state']
        uspsZip = tracking['tracking_status']['location']['zip']
        uspsDate = d1.strftime(new_format)

        if uspsCity is None:
            print("Unavailable")
        elif uspsZip is None:
            print("Unavailable")
        elif uspsState is None:
            print("Unavailable")

        if cmd == 'usps':
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Tracking", color=0x8B4513)
            embed.set_author(name="USPS Tracking", url="https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction?tLabels={}".format(str(tracking_number)), icon_url="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/usps-png-logo/bridgeport-apartments-usps-png-logo-2.png")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/usps-png-logo/bridgeport-apartments-usps-png-logo-2.png")
            embed.add_field(name="Tracking Number: ", value="{}".format(str(tracking_number)), inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Status: ", value="{}".format(str(uspsStatus)), inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Date & Time: ", value="{}".format(str(uspsDate)), inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Location: ", value="{}".format(str(uspsCity) + ", " + str(uspsState) + " " + str(uspsZip)), inline=False)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

client.run(token)
```

On `Line 40` the `uspsCity = tracking['tracking_status']['location']['city']` I get the `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` error. As you can see I attempted to solve it in the way I thought would work, but it still writes the error. Lists and dicts are still slightly confusing to me so that could be why I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

This Error means you tried to get the elements of nothing (None).

```
tracking = shippo.Track.get_status(carrier_token, tracking_number)
```

I guess this function returned None. To avoid this add for example an if statement (try/catch is also possible):

```
if tracking not None:    
    uspsStatus = tracking['tracking_status']['status_details'] + " - " + tracking['tracking_status']['status']
    uspsCity = tracking['tracking_status']['location']['city']
    uspsState = tracking['tracking_status']['location']['state']
    uspsZip = tracking['tracking_status']['location']['zip']
```